# Is SQL Injection itself an issue within Power BI?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I have written a lot of SQL code in recent weeks, as part of a project I'm working on. Having studied it only at university for a term, and briefly in a previous career a few years ago, my SQL knowledge is limited (but growing) and I'm aware that my code is, by and large, full of potential SQL Injection holes, such as:

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT r.LastName, r.Firstname from [Residents-'+@home_name+'] r WHERE r.PersonID NOT IN (
SELECT PersonID FROM [CarePlans-'+@home_name+'] 
WHERE CarePlanType = 0 ) AND r.Location = '''+@home_name+''''
exec(@sql)
```

I've written all of this code in SSMS, into stored procedures, which are then executed via a Delphi application that sits on the same server as SQL Server. I then have PowerBI installed on that server, which is then used to execute those SPs with passed parameters, such as:

```
sp_Get_ResNoCarePlans @home_name = 'Name of Home'
```

When reading up on SQL Injection from various sources, it all seems to be centred around where there are website-based interfaces and users can try and manipulate the URLs to put ; or -- etc in.

I guess my question here, is if it is being used in the manner I've set out, is there really any need to worry specifically about potential SQL security (and not just the normal, Windows kind)? The reason I ask is that whilst I'm sure to most people, avoiding the issue by altering this code would be easy, it doesn't seem as straightforward as it appears because all examples generally talk about PHP or other web interface languages. Am I missing something obvious, or do I perhaps not need to worry about it at this point? I may be being naive, and am happy to accept that, but if someone could give me an honest assessment of my setup described here, I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: SQL Injection is a problem where ever it is; PowerBI or not. Just properly quote your dynamic objects; I.e. `N'...FROM ' + QUOTENAME(N'Residents-'+@home_name) + N'...'`

Comment: Is it as simple as putting in the QuoteName(N'.....?

Comment: `QUOTENAME` will stop dynamic objects being used an an injection source, yes. That is what it's there for; it makes the string into a valid delimit identified value.

Comment: @Larnu thank you very much. If you had written this as an answer, I'd accept it!

Comment: Added an answer, but also, after reviewing, you have far more problems than just the injection of the object name. You *really* need to fundamentally fix your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Injection is a problem regardless of the application you are using. Just because PowerBI is a Microsoft product doesn't mean it's immune to allow Injection through it (just like you can inject through C# or SSMS).

The simple answer here is to use `QUOTENAME`, to properly delimit identify your objects, and `sp_executesql` to pass your parameters properly. This means you end up with a query like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT DISTINCT' + @CRLF +
           N'       r.LastName,' + @CRLF +
           N'       r.FirstName' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(N'Residents-'+@home_name+) + N' r' + @CRLF +
           N'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1' + @CRLF +
           N'                  FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(N'CarePlans-' + @home_name+) + N' cp' + @CRLF +
           N'                  WHERE cp.PersonID = r.PersonID' + @CRLF +
           N'                    AND cp.CarePlanType = 0)' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND r.Location = @home_name;';

--PRINT @SQL; --Your debugging friend

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@home_name sysname', @home_name; --seems odd that @home_name is a parameter and an object name
```

This is untested, as I don't have access to your objects, however, your "friend" will be able to help you.

I cover the principles I use here in my article [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql).

Note, however, that your data appears to be severely denomoralised. Why do you have a different table for every home, when `home_name` is a column in the table? Why would the value of `home_name` be different to that of the table's suffix? This is your *real* problem here and you **need** to normalise your data and fix the design.

Comment: The home_name is a hangover from an earlier bit of code. I need to get rid of it. Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Just to clarify, is it just inside the SET @ SQL=......sections, or for example if when defining the path to a JSON file I would need to QUOTENAME() the @ home_name variable, too? ie SET @ FILEPATH = 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\CMUServer\Win32\Debug\AccidentsReport-'+@ home_name+'.json' ....before the SET @ SQL= to execute?

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking there @Ant ; sounds like you're asking a new question.

Comment: Not really. I'm asking really about where the work needs to be done...do the QuoteName entries need to go in all over the stored procedures, or just where you are constructing the SQL query itself. The example above is not part of the "SELECT...." but is at the top of the SP where, ie, I'm setting out where to obtain the JSON file.

Comment: `QUOTENAME` wraps the names of the dynamic objects @Ant .

Answer (score 1):

While connecting / Querying SQL Server database in Power BI we have 2 methods:

1. Select objects directly
2. Write a query (which in your case will be your stored proc with injection issues)

As far as the user has access credentials to your database, he can pass a malicious statement using the second method, let it be your procedure with injection parameters or some drop/truncate statement.

Comment: That's sort of my point though, in that there aren't really any users other than the powerBI. But, in light of @Larnu's point above, if it's that simple to fix then I'll just stick the QuoteNames in there. Thank you!